# RestSharp XML request and how to get XML response

Tags: c#, restsharp

Hello guys how I can get response XML of this POST request, it all time return only status is OK.
When I test in other tool it response = XML code of SMSes in my modem 3g. Can anyone help me please?

```
public void TestPostwithxmklData()
        {
            string postUrl = "http://192.168.1.1/api/sms/sms-list";
            string xmlData = "<request>" +
                                "<PageIndex>1</PageIndex>" +
                                "<ReadCount>20</ReadCount>" +
                                "<BoxType>1</BoxType>" +
                                "<SortType>0</SortType>" +
                                "<Ascending>0</Ascending>" +
                                "<UnreadPreferred>0</UnreadPreferred>" +
                            "</request>";

            IRestClient client = new RestClient();
            IRestRequest requestX = new RestRequest()
            {
                Resource = postUrl
            };
            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("192.168.100.14", 3128);
            myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            client.Proxy = myproxy;
            
            requestX.AddHeader("Host", "192.168.1.1");
            requestX.AddHeader("User-Agent", "");
            requestX.AddHeader("Referer", "http://192.168.1.1/html/smsinbox.html");
            requestX.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            requestX.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            requestX.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            requestX.AddParameter("XmlBody", xmlData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse<WebRequest> response = client.Post<WebRequest>(requestX);
            Assert.AreEqual(200, (int)response.StatusCode);
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't the response have a Content property, or similar?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? can u explain little more?

Comment: `response.Content` contains the payload. It's always a good idea to read the documentation for libraries and frameworks you use